# Google's Json Parsing Gson library: What's the difference between JsonElement and JsonObject?

Tags: java, android, gson

```
public abstract class JsonElement extends Object
```

A class representing an element of Json. It could either be a JsonObject, a JsonArray, a JsonPrimitive or a JsonNull.

```
public final class JsonObject extends JsonElement
```

A class representing an object type in Json. An object consists of name-value pairs where names are strings, and values are any other type of JsonElement. This allows for a creating a tree of JsonElements. The member elements of this object are maintained in order they were added.

Yay google!

Nevermind that question.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`JsonElement` contains common code for all the valid types in JSON:

- JsonObject
- JsonArray
- JsonPrimitive  (string, number, boolean)
- JsonNull

This allows you a write a method that takes a `JsonElement` that works with any of the above types.

Answer (score 6):

`JsonElement` is the base type for all of the different specific types - it's a base class with common things that all nodes should implement. Logically, this makes a lot of sense.

The thing that all specific types inherits from  `JsonElement` is a good thing for you, too. It allows you to test if an object is a Json node representation, simply by checking if it inherits from `JsonElement`.

The `JsonElement` class is available to you as a public class probably not because you'd want to subclass it, but because you'd want to test for its subclasses.