# get Item's value from json file using Gson

Tags: java, gson

Here i have a little trouble with getting item's value from a JSON string using Gson.

First of all the first part of my code is to get an obejct from massive:

```
String jsonOutput= weatherDataCollect(message);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, JsonElement.class);
        JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
        JsonArray list = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("list");
```

So now if I write:

```
JsonElement todaysWeather = list.get(0);
```

I get exactly what I need - this part of json

```
{"dt":1549281600,"main":{"temp":-0.38,"temp_min":-1.3,"temp_max":-0.38,"pressure":1024.85,"sea_level":1027.5,"grnd_level":1024.85,"humidity":94,"temp_kf":0.91},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"небольшой снегопад","icon":"13d"}],"clouds":{"all":92},"wind":{"speed":2.11,"deg":271.5},"snow":{"3h":0.5445},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2019-02-04 12:00:00"}
```

In JSON massive a lot of parts like this. From everyone I need to get value like this `1549281600` and compare with my to find out which one is closer.

The first part of code shoud look like this

```
        long tomorrowTime = getTomorrowUnixTime();
        long timeDifference = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minDtIndex = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
   JsonElement weatherItem = list.get(i);
   Integer dt = Integer.valueOf(weatherItem.getAsString("dt").toString());
                }
```

But this part `Integer dt = Integer.valueOf(weatherItem.getAsString("dt").toString())` doesnt work.
It should get values from every `dt` and compate to `tomorrowTime`

The second part will look like this:

```
long diff = Math.abs(tomorrowTime - dt);
if(diff < timeDifference){
timeDifference = diff;
minDtIndex = i;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer dt = Integer.valueOf(weatherItem.getAsString("dt").toString());
```

In this line, you are going to get the following compilation error:

```
getAsString( ) 
in JsonElement cannot be applied
```

This is because the `getAsString()` doesn't not accept any parameters, this is your Syntax Error here.

Semantically you have first have interpret the `JSON Element` as `JSON Object`, once it's a JSON Object then you can extract your property named **dt**.

The way to do that is:

```
Integer dt = new Integer(weatherItem.getAsJsonObject().get("dt").getAsInt());
```

I'll reference this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954815/googles-json-parsing-gson-library-whats-the-difference-between-jsonelement-an) and to read about the JSON format itself on [W3-Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

The Rest you can manage on your own logic and coding :) Happy Coding!